# USB Type A to Type A connector

Tags: usb, usbserial

Can anyone please tell me what is the use of USB Type A to Type A cable which is showed in the mentioned link.Link: [http://www.amazon.com/CNE20650-6-Feet-Type-Cable-Black/dp/B00DR0RBV6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DR0RBV6)

Answer (score 0):

This cable would have no use for standard compliant USB devices, but I own one cheap USB=>SATA box that uses USB-A as the *device* plug (instead of B). Those cables are dangerous if one tries to connect e.g. two PCs directly.

Comment: can i transfer the data if i connect USB Type A cables between two devices?